# Prove that $\vec{AI}.\vec{BH}=0$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

First I'm sorry I don't know how to draw the triangle on LaTeX.

We consider $\triangle ABC$ isoscele in $A$. We denote $O$ the midpoint of $[BC]$ and $H$ the orthogonal projection of $O$ on $(AC)$. We also note $I$ the midpoint of $[OH]$.

Is it a good idea to use Apollonius theorem in $\triangle AOH$ and $\triangle HBC$ ?

In that case we will have :

$AO^2+AH^2=\frac{1}{2}OH^2+2AI^2$ and $HB^2+HC^2=\frac{1}{2}BC^2+2OH^2$ and maybe find an expression without $OH^2$ will help.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most elegant solution is the following:

Take $D$ to be the middle of $HC$. Then take a look at $\triangle AOD$.

$DI\parallel OC$ (mid-segment), so $DI\perp AO$.

$OH$ is perpendicular to $AC$ by construction.

So $AI$ is the third altitude: $AI\perp OD$.

But $OD$ is mid-segment of triangle $BHC$ ($OD\parallel BH$)

So $AI\perp BH$, which was to be proved

$\ $

Other proofs (depending on your level):

$\ $

Alternative proof #1: (using similarity)

Consider $E$ the orthogonal projection of $B$ on $AC$ and $F=AI\cap BH$. Then:

$\triangle BEC\sim\triangle AOC\sim\triangle AHO$ (AA case)

So $\frac{CE}{OH}=\frac{CB}{OA}$ and we also have $\frac{CE}{OH}=\frac{CH}{OI}$ (the ratio of halves)

Which means $\triangle OAI\sim\triangle CBH$ (by the SAS similarity case)

Then $\angle OAI=\angle CBH$, so the quadrialater $ABOF$ is inscriptible, so $\angle BFA=\angle BOA=90^{\circ}$

$\ $

Alternative proof #2: (using vectors and the dot product, which is zero iff the vectors are orthogonal, **which dxvi already posted in a shorter solution, so you should follow his instead of mine**)

$$\require{cancel}
\vec{AI}\cdot\vec{BH}=(\vec{AO}+\vec{OI})\cdot(\vec{BC}+\vec{CH})\\
=\cancel{\vec{AO}\cdot\vec{BC}}+\vec{AO}\cdot\vec{CH}+\vec{OI}\cdot\vec{BC}+\cancel{\vec{OI}\cdot\vec{CH}}\\
=\vec{AO}\cdot\vec{CH}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{OH}\cdot2\vec{OC}=\vec{AO}\cdot\vec{CH}+\vec{OH}\cdot\vec{OC}\\
=\vec{AO}\cdot(\vec{CO}+\vec{OH})+\vec{OH}\cdot\vec{OC}=\cancel{\vec{AO}\cdot\vec{CO}}+\vec{AO}\cdot\vec{OH}+\vec{OH}\cdot\vec{OC}\\
=\vec{OH}\cdot(\vec{AO}+\vec{OC})=\vec{OH}\cdot\vec{AC}=0$$

which implies $\vec{AI}\perp \vec{BH}$

$\ $

Alternative proof #3: (using analytic geometry)

Let $A(0,a)$, $B(-b,0)$ and $C(0,b)$

The slope of $AC$ is $-\frac{a}{b}$ and the equation of $AC$ is $y=-\frac{a}{b}x+a$

The slope of $OH$ is $\frac{b}{a}$ (negative reciprocal) and the equation of $OH$ is $y=\frac{b}{a}x$

Then solve the system of the two equations above to calculate the coordinates of $H$, say $(u,v)$ as a function of $a$ and $b$.

Then the coordinates of $I$ are just $\left(\frac{u}{2},\frac{v}{2}\right)$ (midpoint)

Then calculate the slopes of $AI$ and $BH$ and show they are negative reciprocals.

Comment: Ok but why $AI$ is perpendicular to $OD$ ?

Comment: Because the altitudes are concurrent ($I$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle AOD)$

Comment: The two other altitudes are $OH$ and $DI$ right ?

Comment: That's true....

Comment: Nice geometric solution (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Since the title invites a vector proof, note that by construction:

$$
\begin{align}
& \overrightarrow{BO}=\overrightarrow{OC} && \text{since } O \text{ is the midpoint of } BC \tag{1} \\
& \overrightarrow{AO} \cdot \overrightarrow{BC}=0 && \text{since } \triangle ABC \text{ is isosceles, so } AO \perp BC\tag{2} \\
& \overrightarrow{OH} \cdot \overrightarrow{AC}=0 && \text{since } OH \perp AC \tag{3} \\
& \overrightarrow{AI} = \frac{1}{2}(\overrightarrow{AO}+\overrightarrow{AH}) && \text{since }  I \text{ is the midpoint of } OH \tag{4} 
\end{align}
$$

Then:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
2 \overrightarrow{AI} \cdot \overrightarrow{BH} &= (\overrightarrow{AO}+\overrightarrow{AH})\cdot(\overrightarrow{BO}+\overrightarrow{OH}) && \text{by } (4) \\
 &= \cancel{\overrightarrow{AO}\cdot\overrightarrow{BO}} + \overrightarrow{AO}\cdot\overrightarrow{OH}+\overrightarrow{AH}\cdot\overrightarrow{BO}+\bcancel{\overrightarrow{AH}\cdot\overrightarrow{OH}} && \text{by } (2), (3) \\
 &= (\cancel{\overrightarrow{AH}}+\overrightarrow{HO})\cdot\overrightarrow{OH} + (\bcancel{\overrightarrow{AO}}+\overrightarrow{OH})\cdot\overrightarrow{OC} && \text{by } (2),(3),(1) \\
 &= -\overrightarrow{OH}\cdot\overrightarrow{OH} + \overrightarrow{OH}\cdot(\overrightarrow{OH}+\cancel{\overrightarrow{HC}}) && \text{by } (3)\\
 &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $\vec{AI}=\vec{AO}+\vec{OI}=\vec{AO} + 1/2\vec{OH}=1/2\vec{AO}+1/2\vec{AH}$. We cannot use Apollonius ?

Comment: @Maman Not sure whether your comment was meant to prove $(4)\,$, that's common enough that it's usually assumed as known. Otherwise it's easy to prove from scratch: $$2 \overrightarrow{AI} = \overrightarrow{AI}+\overrightarrow{AI} = (\overrightarrow{AO}+\overrightarrow{OI})+(\overrightarrow{AH}+\overrightarrow{HI})=\overrightarrow{AO}+\overrightarrow{AH}$$ because $\overrightarrow{OI}+\overrightarrow{HI}=0$ when $I$ is the midpoint of $OH$.

Comment: No it's ok, but I was just wondering if the proof would work just by using apollonius

Comment: @Maman I guess you could calculate the actual lengths (maybe using Apollonius) then verify that $AB^2+IH^2=BI^2+AH^2$ which would mean that the quadrilateral $ABIH$ is [orthodiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodiagonal_quadrilateral).